# Client DOM , view source does not have gridview inside update panel

Tags: javascript, jquery, asp.net, gridview, webforms

I  have a DIV which I want to print using jQuery. That div has a update panel and datagrid inside it.

```
<div id="DivSaved" class="tab-pane fade">
  <div class ="row">
    <asp:UpdatePanel ID="UpdatePanelSaved" runat="server" UpdateMode="Conditional">
      <ContentTemplate>
        <asp:HiddenField ID="HiddenKeyIDId" runat="server" Value="" />  
        <asp:GridView ID="GridViewB001" runat="server" AutoGenerateColumns="False" CssClass="table table-hover table-condensed menuGrid" GridLines="None" DataSourceID="DS_B001" DataKeyNames="KeyId" OnRowDataBound="GridViewBVDVSavedTemplate_OnRowDataBound" >
```

Now when I try to print DivSaves using jQuery:

```
$('#DivSaved').print()
```

There is main div, but no content inside as anything inside updatepanel is not getting rendered.

When I view source, there are no grid view or update panel or any other control inside updatepanel.

Comment: Firstly is `print()` a method added by an third-party library? It's not a standard jQuery method. Secondly, the 'view source' page will never show dynamically added content - it's the state of the page as it was loaded, so that is expected behaviour.

Comment: @RoryMcCrossan, have a linked  to script plugin  for print. Is there any way to get dynamically added content. There should be some way as I am able to see them on chrome  devtools.